# Does each firebase user automatically have an email address, no matter what sign-in-method is used?

Tags: firebase, email, firebase-authentication, provider

Obviously, if you sign in anonymously, you have no email address, and if you sign in with email, you have one.

But what if I sign in with Google, Apple, Facebook, etc... Will each firebase user just get the email address, which is assigned to the Google, Apple... account? Or is there a possibility that some users will have `null` as their email address?

I want to know this, because I want to have a **list of users** in my app (admins more specifically, so not a very large list), but I don't want to use their `uid` to display in a list. I want to use something more **readable** to a human, like their email address (or their `displayName`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Firebase Authentication uses the email address as a primary identifier for the user, it *is* possible for a user to not have an email address - for example when the OAuth provider doesn't provide this information.

If you want to display a meaningful value for each user, I'd recommend combining the email address and display name for the best chance of having something recognizable.

Comment: Do you know which OAuth provider does/does not provide the users email? Or under which circumstances?

Comment: iirc Facebook limited login and anonymous auth are now the only providers that never will have an email address, but you can remove the scope for any provider when making the OAuth request.